# Django filter using select_related()

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have the following query which works perfectly:

```
    campaignFixtures = UserSelection.objects.select_related().filter(user=currentUserID,campaignno=currentCampaignNo).order_by('fixtureid__fixturedate')[:1]
```

However, I need to filter a field from another table as follows:

```
    campaignFixtures = UserSelection.objects.select_related().filter(user=currentUserID,campaignno=currentCampaignNo,straightredfixture__fixturematchday=18).order_by('fixtureid__fixturedate')[:1]
```

But, I am receiving the following error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'straightredfixture' into field. Choices are: campaignno, fixtureid, fixtureid_id, teamselection1or2, teamselectionid, teamselectionid_id, user, user_id, userselectionid
```

The models are as follows:

```
class StraightredFixture(models.Model):
    fixtureid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    home_team = models.ForeignKey('straightred.StraightredTeam', db_column='hometeamid', related_name='home_fixtures')
    away_team = models.ForeignKey('straightred.StraightredTeam', db_column='awayteamid', related_name='away_fixtures')
    fixturedate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    fixturestatus = models.CharField(max_length=24,null=True)
    fixturematchday = models.ForeignKey('straightred.StraightredFixtureMatchday', db_column='fixturematchday')
    spectators = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    hometeamscore = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    awayteamscore = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    homegoaldetails = models.TextField(null=True)
    awaygoaldetails = models.TextField(null=True)
    hometeamyellowcarddetails = models.TextField(null=True)
    awayteamyellowcarddetails = models.TextField(null=True)
    hometeamredcarddetails = models.TextField(null=True)
    awayteamredcarddetails = models.TextField(null=True)
    soccerseason = models.ForeignKey('straightred.StraightredSeason', db_column='soccerseasonid', related_name='fixture_season')


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fixtureid

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'straightred_fixture'

class UserSelection(models.Model):
    userselectionid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    campaignno = models.CharField(max_length=36,unique=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='selectionUser')
    teamselection1or2 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    teamselectionid = models.ForeignKey('straightred.StraightredTeam', db_column='teamselectionid', related_name='teamID')
    fixtureid = models.ForeignKey('straightred.StraightredFixture', db_column='fixtureid')


    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'straightred_userselection'
```

Any help would be appreciated, Alan.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the problem is related to `selected_related`. You are just trying to filter using a wrong lookup value. How about filtering with `fixtureid__fixturematchday` instead:

```
UserSelection.objects.select_related().filter(user=currentUserID, campaignno=currentCampaignNo, fixtureid__fixturematchday=18).order_by('fixtureid__fixturedate')[:1]
```

Since you want to get only a single object, why don't you just use [`.first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#first) to get an object instead of a queryset with one item:

```
campaignFixture = UserSelection.objects.select_related("fixtureid").filter(...).order_by(...).first()
```

Comment: Many thanks, I was so close.  Really appreciate the additional information.

Comment: Really, this is an indication you should change the field name in your model.

Answer (score 2):

According to your model, the relationship is the fixtureid

```
 UserSelection.objects.select_related().filter(user=currentUserID,campaignno=currentCampaignNo,fixtureid__fixturematchday=18)
```

Comment: @alantingey - no worries, the only time you need the class name is when you're looking up via a reverse relationship where a related name isnt specified